# Are the homology groups for simplicial homology and singular homology with coeeficients the same?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space with a  $\Delta$-complex structure. We know that $H_n^\Delta(X)\cong H_n(x)$ (Theorem 2.27 Algebraic Topology Hatcher). My question is the following: Does this also hold for other coefficients than $\mathbb{Z}$?

To be more precise:

Let $A$ be an abelian group, and let $H_n(X;A)$ denote the object resulting from applying the following composition of functors to $X$:
$$
\textbf{Top}\overset{\text{Singular Chains}}{\longrightarrow}\textbf{Ch}\overset{\square \otimes_\mathbb{Z}A}{\longrightarrow}\textbf{Ch}\overset{H_n}{\longrightarrow}\textbf{Ab}.
$$
Let $H_n^\Delta(X;A)$ denote the object resulting from applying the following composition of functors to the chain complex of simplicial chains $\Delta_*(X)$:
$$
\textbf{Ch}\overset{\square \otimes_\mathbb{Z}A}{\longrightarrow}\textbf{Ch}\overset{H_n}{\longrightarrow}\textbf{Ab}.
$$
Is it true that $H_n(X;A)\cong H_n^\Delta(X;A)$?

Comment: I seem to remember from my algebraic topology course that any two sequences of functors satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Steenrod_axioms) are naturally isomorphic if they have the same coefficient ring, i.e. if they agree on the one point space.

Comment: I will try and look into this.

Comment: In the present form the question is misleading. Your second functor is not defined on $\mathbf{Top}$, but on the category of $\Delta$-complexes.

Comment: You are right. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I am 100% sure the proof goes through with coefficients in any abelian group $A$.

2) If you don't want to look at the proof again, it follows for any coefficient group $A$ from the case of $\Bbb Z$, the five-lemma, and the universal coefficient theorem.